# What is the right way to create an object that can be passed around to different layers

Tags: c#, oop

I am new to programming so sorry i am not clear on things

I created a class let say

```
public class Users 
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

My first question is where should i put this class in term of the 3 layer design

If i put it in the `Business layer`, when i need to update the data access layer i would like to pass the Users object to `Data access layer` like this

```
sendDataToDB(List<Users);
```

on the data access layer, VS would generate this method for me

```
public static void sendDataToDB(List<global::BLL.Users> newUsers)
{

}
```

But there would be error saying:

> The type or namespace name 'BLL' could not be found in the global
>   namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Right now i just create another library that contain the Users object and give all three layers access to that library.

I really dont think that is the right way to do things. So any suggestion would be great

Comment: You've tagged this as three-tier but discuss layers in the details.  A tier and a layer are different things; are you talking about tiers or just layers?

Comment: i just remove the Tiers, i am talking about layers. Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

If your User object just contains data and no behavior it seems to be a data object which bundles data related to user. In this case it's a data object and can be passed across layers. You could probably create a separate namespace or even assembly for that.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object

Comment: So it would make sense to have a assembly that contain the object? Yes the object only contains data and no others.

Comment: a "layer" only takes dependencies on adjacent lower layers. A Data class shared with Business *and* UI means Data, Business, and UI are no longer "layers".

Comment: @PeterRitchie Does DateTime class violates layers?

Comment: DateTime is not declared in any of your layers; it's an intrinsic type  so you can use it where ever it's needed.

Comment: To be clear, you can add any infrastructural types you like outside of your layers...

Comment: Things like Entities (i.e. things that have *identity*) are generally business-specific and usually belong in a Business layer with DTO objects that represent it, potentially in lower (Data) layers.

Answer (score 0):

The rules of Layering is that lower layers can know nothing of higher layers.  For all three layers to see a particular class, it has to be in the lowest layer.  This generally means the data access layer--which "Users" may be more of a Business concern.

The other problem with layers is you don't generally pass-along dependencies that a lower layer has to it's upper layers (at least dependencies on other layers).  e.g. a business layer that depends on a data layer generally shields the data layer from the layer about the business layer...

This really means that classes that need to be shared between all layers should be outside of the three layers.

I recommend having a Business class AND a Data class.  the Business layer knows how to get the Data class and translate it into a business class for higher layers.  e.g. you may have Data.Users that you use to query/update data in a database.  The Business layer uses that to query/update to the database and translates it into Business.Users that is then given to higher layers...

Some useful layering interaction rules: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx#Step5](http://bit.ly/IOznDa)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question, and one of those issues where I still think "it's 2012 , why is this still so hard?".

So, you have a 3 tier solution: User Interface, Domain / Business Logic, Data / Persistence. In an ideal world you want to be able to display your User class in the UI, define the User class and it's logic in the BL and be able to pass it to a Data repository to be saved to the database. Unfortunately you can't do this with 3 tiers because of circular dependencies.

A common solution is to use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) so each tier has it's own version of (for example) User class, and you just map between like object in tiers. A tool like AutoMapper allows your Complex Domain Model to be mapped to a simpler UI display type class.  The Domain Object (even if it is made of other objects) can then be mapped to the type of object that it's specific repository requires - again using AutoMapper (you don't have to use AutoMapper by the way, it just makes the mapping less dull).

Another option is to perhaps break out of three tiers, and have a fourth 'DTO' tier available 'horizontally' to each 'vertical' layer. I tend to map them though.

New versions of EF put the classes created by EF all the way into the UI View, but this just feels wrong to me and is not what I know about, but might work for you?

I'm sure other people will have other suggestions too. I'll watch this one with interest.